# svn / Tortoise checkout from trunk to a working copy of branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, trunk

SVN, trunk (mainline) for Product, I have my own branch.

I need to copy a selected file from trunk to my own branch. To do that I:

- rclick working copy folder
- select TortoiseSVN/Repo browser
- go to Product/trunk location, find a file in a subfolder
- rclick file, select Checkout, select relevant folder in working copy (of branch)

I get error:

```
'/somewhere/Product/' is already a working copy for a different URL
```

So what that it is a working copy? I want that file explicitly overwritten.

P.S. if I select "Copy to" after rclicking the file in Repo browser and type path to relevant subfolder in my branch, a commit message text popup appears. Type the message, click OK and get error "path already exists". aaargh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't checkout from different sources into single WC. Period

If you want to have some objects from different subtree in your tree (trunk's files in branch) and perform it in **natural** (Subversion) way you **must** to [merge subtree](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync.subtree)